# Missing delimiter (. inserted)

Tags: math-mode

The code below produces the error

> Missing delimiter (. inserted).

```
{\it \begin{equation}
        $E_{k} = 10\log_{10}\left{ \frac{\sum_{i=1}^{M_{k}}{{\left[W_{k}^{P} x(i)\right]}^{2}}}{M_{k}}\right} (dB), \hspace{5em} k = 1,2,....,N\hspace{7em}$
        \end{equation}}\\
```

Comment: The error indicates a unmatched `\left..\right` pair.

Answer (score 6):

Let me reformat your code to better understand what's wrong.

```
{\it
 \begin{equation}
    $E_{k} = 10\log_{10}
    \left{
    \frac{\sum_{i=1}^{M_{k}}{{\left[W_{k}^{P} x(i)\right]}^{2}}}{M_{k}}
    \right} (dB), \hspace{5em} k = 1,2,....,N\hspace{7em}$
    \end{equation}}\\
```

- There is no need to have a group around the equation.
- The command `\it` does nothing useful and, besides, it has been deprecated for twenty years
- You ***don't*** want `$` inside `\begin{equation}`
- `\left{` is illegal; you want to have a growing brace and the command for *printing* an open brace is `\{`
- You seem to have lost the count of braces, due to the fraction. You probably wanted

  ```
  \frac{\sum_{i=1}^{M_{k}} [W_{k}^{P} x(i)]^{2}}{M_{k}}
  ```

  (note that `\left[` and `\right]` are not necessary, they're even bad!)
- `\right}` is similar to the above.
- ellipsis should be denoted by `\dots`
- The final `\hspace{7em}` serves no purpose

So, here's a better realization

```
\begin{equation}
  E_{k}=10\log_{10}
  \left\{
    \frac{ \sum_{i=1}^{M_{k}} [W_{k}^{P} x(i)]^{2} }{ M_{k} }
  \right\}
  \,\mathrm{dB},
  \qquad k=1,2,\dots,N
\end{equation}
```

You probably also want to use `siunitx` for units, so `\,\mathrm{dB}` can better become `\si{\decibel}`, which is even much clearer, isn't it?

[image]

The fraction appears to be quite crowded, though; better set the denominator in front of the summation:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
  E_{k}=10\log_{10}
  \biggl\{
    \frac{1}{M_{k}} \sum_{i=1}^{M_{k}} [W_{k}^{P} x(i)]^{2}
  \biggr\}
  \si{\decibel},
  \qquad k=1,2,\dots,N
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I know it's not your cup of tea, but I would prefer `\bigl[...\bigr]` especially given that the superscript `P` is so optically large. Also, there could be a thin space before the unit.

Answer (score 2):

There are many issues with your code.

1. Don't use `\it`: it has been replaced by `\textit` and `\itshape`. None of these commands affects maths mode.
2. Don't use dollar signs in the maths environments: they automatically enter maths mode.
3. Don't use manual line breaks after displayed maths: the spacing is handled automatically.
4. Use the `siunitx` package to format physical units.
5. Use `\dots` to print a correctly-spaced ellipsis.
6. When printing braces, use `\{` and `\}`.

Your code should be

```
\begin{equation}
  E_{k} = 10\log_{10}\left\{\frac{\sum_{i=1}^{M_{k}}{{\left[W_{k}^{P}x(i)\right]}^{2}}}{M_{k}}\right\} (\si{\decibel}), \hspace{5em} k = 1,2,\dots,N
\end{equation}
```

Comment: `\dots` instead of `....`? But much more relevant: `\left{` and `\right}` are still wrong.